# Not able to register a service as Eureka Client and not able to see Discovery client in log

Tags: java, spring, microservices, pom.xml, netflix-eureka

I have 2 microservices project, One for eureka server and other for UserService(client) , and my eureka server is running successfully on port 8761. But even after running my UserService I'm not able to see the inctances in dashboard of eureka server also there is no log for UserService for DiscoveryClient. Here is my application.properties for UserService :
server.port=8081

```
spring.application.name=user-service

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
```

Here is my application.properties for ServiceRegistry : # Eureka Server Configuration
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=service-registry

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

I have also added @EnableEurekaClient in UserService. In pom.xml for userservice :

```
`<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version> 
    </properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Eureka Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>,  <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>`
```

Also here is my Service Registry pom.xml :

```
`<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties><dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency><dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>`
```

Comment: Is UserService starting without any errors?